# How to generate a lot of (blank) images files?

Tags: shell-script, imagemagick, images

For a test, I need to quickly create 1700 jpg-images (even blank) in a defined size 1000x706. I wonder if we could do this with a shell script or a program (like ImageMagick). I wish they called `img_0.jpg`, `img_1.jpg`…

Someone knows a simple solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following should work for your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert -size 1000x706 xc:white img_0.jpg || { printf '%s\n' 'Failed to create original image' ; exit 1 ; }
for (( _num = 1 ; _num < 1700 ; _num++ )); do
   cp img_0.jpg "img_${_num}.jpg" || { printf '%s\n' "Failed to copy to image img_${_num}.jpg" ; exit 2 ; }
done
```

ImageMagick creates the first image, and then it is copied to make up 1700 files. If `ulimit` doesn't restrict you from doing it (it probably will) and you have enough file descriptors, you could replace the loop with:

```
tee img_{1..1699}.jpg > /dev/null < img_0.jpg
```

You could also use the shorter idiom (with a larger memory requirement to store all of the numbers at once) `for _num in {1..1699}` in recent `bash` versions, but you don't specify which shells are available. `((` is available in most shells (`bash`, `ksh`, and `ash` at least, not sure about others).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try this in a few hours. Thank you for the idea =) I vote for your answer as soon as I have enough points

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scriptable way to create lots of non-blank images, maybe consider: https://perlmaven.com/drawing-images-using-gd-simple